# function that returns a version of the given arrays where each zero value in the array is replaced by the smallest odd value to the right of 0. In C

Tags: arrays, c, function, loops, pointers

I'm having a bit of trouble with this problem. The full text of the problem is as follows : "Write a function that returns a version of the given array of non-negative integers where each zero value in the
array is replaced by the smallest odd value to the right of the zero in the array. If there is no odd value to the right of the zero,
leave the zero as a zero."

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void lowestOdd(int num[], int size) {
    int i, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (num[i] % 2 != 0 && num[i] < num[i + 1]) {
            temp = num[i];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (num[i] = 0) {
            num[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}

void printArray(int array[], int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d/n", array[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int i, size;
    int myarr[20];
    printf("What is the size of your array? \n");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &myarr[i]);
    }
    lowestOdd(myarr[20], size);
    printArray(myarr[20], size);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried implementing pointers in the lowestOdd function, but to no avail. I do think they're necessary here, but I'm not really that good at pointers. The warnings I get are mostly 'warning: passing argument 1 of 'lowestOdd' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]'. Also, in my code, I haven't added the statements that would check whether the number is a zero or whether there are any odd values to the right of the zero.

Comment: Not reading well, `if (num[i] = 0)` looks suspicious.

Comment: If you use `gcc` or `clang` to compile this, add the compiler options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`  and fix all warnings and errors. [Like this](https://godbolt.org/z/3556orxz3)

Comment: Thank you all, I've tried changing if(num[i] = 0 ) to if(num[i] == 0) but there's still errors... It returns a segmentation fault now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations)

```
int myarr[20];
```

`myarr` is the *identifier* - the name used to refer to the array itself. `myarr` has the *type* `int [20]`.

When used in this expression

```
lowestOdd(myarr[20], size);
```

`[20]` is the [array subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access), accessing index `20`. This is index is out of bounds, as the valid indices for the *type* `int [20]` are `0` to `19`. This out of bounds access will cause [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

This warning

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'lowestOdd' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

is given because, although an invalid index to access, the *expression* `myarr[20]` evaluates to an `int`. `lowestOdd` expects an `int *` as its first argument.

Similar to before, in

```
if (num[i] % 2 != 0 && num[i] < num[i + 1])
```

`num[i + 1]` will access `num[size]` when `i` is `size - 1` (again, valid indices are `0` to `size - 1`).

This is assignment

```
if (num[i] = 0)
```

where you want a comparison

```
if (num[i] == 0)
```

Note that

```
scanf("%d", &size);

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &myarr[i]);
```

risks the same out of bounds access if the user enters a value *greater* than `20` for `size`.

---

Ignoring the out of bounds access for a moment, `lowestOdd` attempts to find the last occurrence of the smaller number from each pair of numbers in the array, where the left number must be odd.

It then replaces all zeroes in the array with this value.

There is a chance `temp` is never assigned anything, and thus has an indeterminate value.

This is not correct.

---

Here is an example program (using a [variable-length array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays)).

Note that the syntax `array + i` is equivalent to `&array[i]`.

`? :` is the [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator): in `a ? b : c`, if `a` is non-zero the expression evaluates to `b`, else it evaluates to `c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int min(int a, int b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

int find_lowest_odd(int *base, size_t len)
{
    int value = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (base[i] & 1) /* base[i] % 2 != 0 */
            value = value ? min(value, base[i]) : base[i];

    return value;
}

void mutate_array(int *a, size_t len)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (0 == a[i])            /* search from the next position */
            a[i] = find_lowest_odd(a + i + 1, len - i - 1);
}

void print_array(int *a, size_t len)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void) {
    size_t size;

    printf("What is the size of your array?: ");

    if (1 != scanf("%zu", &size))
        return 1;

    int array[size];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("#%zu: ", i + 1);

        if (1 != scanf("%d", array + i))
            return 1;
    }

    print_array(array, size);
    mutate_array(array, size);
    print_array(array, size);
}
```

I/O:

```
What is the size of your array?: 10
#1: 0
#2: 2
#3: 0
#4: 5
#5: 3
#6: 0
#7: 7
#8: 2
#9: 0
#10: 0
0 2 0 5 3 0 7 2 0 0
3 2 3 5 3 7 7 2 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you can try this.
Here's my naive approach. For every zero in the array it is checking for the smallest odd element from that position to the last index and storing it in variable named smaller. After checking it replaces the original value of that index with smaller one.

```
#include<stdio.h>  
void lowestOdd(int *num, int size){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
        if (num[i] != 0) continue;
        int smaller = 99998;
        for(j = i+1; j < size; j++){
            if (num[j] % 2 != 0 && num[j] < smaller) smaller = num[j];
        }
        if (smaller != 99998) num[i] = smaller;
    }
}

void printArray(int *array, int size){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
}

int main()  
{  
    int i, size;
    int myarr[20];
    printf("What is the size of your array? \n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
        scanf("%d", &myarr[i]);
    }
    lowestOdd(myarr, size);
    printArray(myarr, size);
    return 0;  
}
```